# Why is this value not being implicitly returned in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, return, implicit

I thought that when using Ruby, the last line of an expression is implicitly returned without having to use the 'return' keyword.  However, in my code below, the correct value is only returned if I use the return keyword.

```
def find_the_cheese(ings)
  cheese_types = ["cheddar", "gouda", "camembert"]
  i = 0
  while i < ings.length do
    if cheese_types.include?(ings[i])
      ings[i]  #=> only works if 'return' keyword is in front of it
    end
    i += 1
  end
  nil
end

find_the_cheese(["water", "gouda", "crackers"])
```

The if-statement on line 5 is supposed to evaluate to true, and therefore it should return the value of ings[i], which is "gouda".  However, if I don't write "return" in front of the value, the whole thing evaluates to nil.  But if I write "return" then it gives the correct answer.
There have been other times when using ruby that I have left out the return keyword and it returned the value I expected, so how come sometimes it works and other times it doesn't?

Comment: "I thought that when using Ruby, the **last line** of an expression is implicitly returned" – Hint #1: what is the last line of the method? "The if-statement on **line 5**" – Hint #2: is line 5 the last line?

Comment: In Ruby, you rarely have to traverse an array using indices, explicit counter variables and low-level loops. There's almost always a more succinct way given Ruby's rich [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html) module. For example, your above code could be rewritten as: `ings.find { |ing| cheese_types.include?(ing) }` – and it works without an explicit `return`.

Answer (score 3):

In your function, you have `nil` as the last line, so unless you leave the function before this point by using `return`, you will always end at `nil` and thus always return `nil`, since Ruby implicitly returns the last expression evaluated, as you said yourself.

In short, you have to use `return`, because line 5 is not the last line of the function, and without it, it will run all the way through to `nil`. And thus will return it.

Comment: _"the last line"_ can be quite misleading. Better think of _"the last expression evaluated"_.